# How to Use iOS Default System Font (SF Pro Text/Display) with Core Text's CTFontCreateWithName

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, core-text

I'm working on an iOS application where I need to render text using Core Text for more precise control over text layout. I want to use the default system font, which I understand is SF Pro Text for text sizes below 20 points and SF Pro Display for sizes 20 points and above. My goal is to ensure that my application matches the system's look and feel as closely as possible, especially in terms of typography.

I'm aware that CTFontCreateWithName requires a font name string, but I'm unsure how to specify SF Pro Text or SF Pro Display dynamically based on text size, considering iOS automatically switches between these two variants.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
let fontSize: CGFloat = 18 // Example size
let fontName = "What should this be?" // How do I specify SF Pro Text or Display dynamically?
let fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(fontName as CFString, fontSize, nil)
```

Questions:

1. What is the correct way to specify the font name for SF Pro Text or SF Pro Display when using CTFontCreateWithName, so it aligns with iOS's automatic font selection based on size?
2. Is there a recommended approach for dynamically selecting between SF Pro Text and SF Pro Display, or should I directly use one of them for all text sizes?
3. Are there any considerations or best practices when using the system font with Core Text to ensure my application's typography remains consistent with the rest of the iOS ecosystem?

Any guidance, code snippets, or references to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you just need [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfont/3747569-init)? By the way, I'd suggest editing your question to only ask a single question.

Answer (score 1):

The correct tool is [CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1511312-ctfontcreateuifontforlanguage#). This is not possible with CTFontCreateWithName. The "name" of the default font is ".SFUI-Regular", but you can't actually pass that.

Note that language can be important here, when you know it. There are other SF system fonts, such as [SF Arabic](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110381/), SF Georgian, and others. If you pass NULL, though, it'll use the current system language. (For your use case, trying to match the system as closely as possible, this is likely your best choice.)

As Sweeper points out in the comments, it looks like there's are new [Swift overlays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/ctfont) to make the syntax a little nicer. I haven't used them, but I'm sure they're wrappers on CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage.

Comment: but if i want to draw unicode text with arabic and latin characters (and chineses also why not), what language should i use ?

Comment: You would generally use the current language (NULL). These fonts (and fonts generally) "cascade," which is to say that they look for a glyph in the first font, and if that font does not have the glyph, they proceed to the next font, and so on until they can find the required glyph. So it will work out. But if you know the language in question, you can set up the cascade better, and many glyphs exist in multiple fonts and will be more harmonious if you select more from the same one. (SF fonts are designed to work together of course.)

Comment: For example, I don't believe any of the SF fonts have Chinese glyphs. I believe it currently falls back to one of the PingFang fonts. (Edited the answer a bit to make it clearer that while language is important, for your particular case, NULL, or the CTFont inits that don't require language, are probably ideal, since it's just "do what the system would do.")